# Iterate TestScripts with multiple data in Excel using POI HSSF

Tags: java, apache, selenium, apache-poi

I have written testcase in selenium with one set of data in excel, But i need to run with multiple set of data. I have tried looping my testcases but no luck. Experts please provide me code for looping my testcase with multiple set of data. Below is my code for your reference.***ExcelUtil file code***

```
public static XSSFCell getCellData(int RowNum, int ColNum) throws Exception {

        try {
         Cell = sheet.getRow(RowNum).getCell(ColNum);
         if (Cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
         Cell.getNumericCellValue();
         } else if (Cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
         Cell.getStringCellValue();
         }

        } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

        return Cell;

    }
```

***Test method***

```
public static void Accountcreation() throws Exception {

        orprop = testobjects.get_testobjects();
        sheet = xlsdata.xls_Reading("Sheet2");


    XSSFCell name = xlsdata.getCellData(1,0);
        XSSFCell email = xlsdata.getCellData(1, 1);
        XSSFCell website = xlsdata.getCellData(1, 2);
        XSSFCell billingaddress = xlsdata.getCellData(1, 3);
        XSSFCell city = xlsdata.getCellData(1, 4);
        XSSFCell state = xlsdata.getCellData(1, 5);
        XSSFCell postalcode = xlsdata.getCellData(1,6);
        XSSFCell country = xlsdata.getCellData(1, 7);
        XSSFCell description = xlsdata.getCellData(1, 8);
        XSSFCell siccode = xlsdata.getCellData(1, 9);


        commonutilities.click_button("xpath",
                orprop.getProperty("crm_menu_account_css"), wd);
        commonutilities.implicity_wait(30, wd);
        commonutilities.click_button("xpath",orprop.getProperty("crm_account_createaccount_xpath"), wd);

        Assert.assertEquals(wd.getTitle(), "Accounts");
        commonutilities.get_text_from_excel("xpath",
                orprop.getProperty("crm_account_name_xpath"), name, wd);
        commonutilities.get_text_from_excel("xpath",
                orprop.getProperty("crm_account_email_xpath"), email, wd);
        commonutilities.select_list_items("xpath",
                orprop.getProperty("crm_account_phone_xpath"), "Office", wd);
        commonutilities.get_text_from_excel("xpath",
                orprop.getProperty("crm_account_website_xpath"), website, wd);
        commonutilities.get_text_from_excel("xpath",
                orprop.getProperty("crm_account_billingaddress_xpath"),
                billingaddress, wd);
        commonutilities.get_text_from_excel("xpath",
                orprop.getProperty("crm_account_city_xpath"), city, wd);
        commonutilities.get_text_from_excel("xpath",
                orprop.getProperty("crm_account_state_xpath"), state, wd);
        commonutilities.get_text_from_excel("xpath",
                orprop.getProperty("crm_account_postalcode_xpath"), postalcode,
                wd);
        commonutilities.get_text_from_excel("xpath",
                orprop.getProperty("crm_account_country_xpath"), country, wd);
        commonutilities.click_button("Xpath",
                orprop.getProperty("crm_account_copybilling_xpath"), wd);
        // details
        commonutilities.get_text_from_excel("xpath",
                orprop.getProperty("crm_account_description_xpath"),
                description, wd);
        commonutilities.get_text_from_excel("xpath",
                orprop.getProperty("crm_account_details_siccode_xpath"),
                siccode, wd);
        commonutilities.select_list_items("xpath",
                orprop.getProperty("crm_account_details_type_xpath"),
                "Investor", wd);
        commonutilities.select_list_items("xpath",
                orprop.getProperty("crm_account_details_industry_xpath"),
                "Education", wd);
        commonutilities.click_button("xpath",
                orprop.getProperty("crm_account_save_xpath"), wd);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use sheet.getLastRowNum() to get the total row count and loop through that as shown below.

```
public static void Accountcreation() throws Exception {

    orprop = testobjects.get_testobjects();
    sheet = xlsdata.xls_Reading("Sheet2");

    for(i=0;i<sheet.getLastRowNum();i++){
       XSSFCell name = xlsdata.getCellData(1,0);
       XSSFCell email = xlsdata.getCellData(i, 1);
       XSSFCell website = xlsdata.getCellData(i, 2);
       XSSFCell billingaddress = xlsdata.getCellData(i, 3);
       XSSFCell city = xlsdata.getCellData(i, 4);
       XSSFCell state = xlsdata.getCellData(i, 5);
       XSSFCell postalcode = xlsdata.getCellData(i,6);
       XSSFCell country = xlsdata.getCellData(i, 7);
       XSSFCell description = xlsdata.getCellData(i, 8);
       XSSFCell siccode = xlsdata.getCellData(i, 9);

       // Other Code Section
    }

}
```

Comment: Great to know. Accept and upload the answer, when you can.

Comment: I guess i can't vote for my own post :), I request you to do that behalf of me.

Comment: I can't do on my own answer. You can accept/upvote when you get eligible for it. Thanks.